# Halp! The favicon is faceless!

Tags: bug, status-completed, favicon, site-design

[image]

I have a Retina display, and the favicon is faceless, plain, and depressing everywhere I go. Can we please fix this?

Easy Repro Steps:

1. Open Chrome (haven't tested it on anything else)
2. Zoom in (command-<kbd>+</kbd> on a Mac) to 200%
3. Go to Arduino.SE
4. Observe the facelessness of the icon.

Comment: 'Tis fine on my end.  (Vista, FF 26)

Comment: It only does this on a Retina display.

Comment: I suppose so, no bug for me either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the bug... when you zoom to 200% the code detects this and change the fav icons sprites file from [this](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=2a2968ded8b1ccc425e160db793c03e1) (16x16 icons) to [that](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=6edcecf7b8efae77d1bf2212ca614a95) (32x32). (Very smart, team! :))

Now the only problem is, that while in the 16x16 sprite there is icon for 
Arduino, in the 32x32 it's just blank as you see yourself.

With proper icon:

> [image]

And without:

> [image]

**Update:**

Fixed [by Jin](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/halp-the-favicon-is-faceless/23?noredirect=1#comment58_23), in revision `2014.2.??.1369`.

Comment: This was my fault. I've pushed the correct icons. The changes will be on live after our next prod build. (You may still have to hard refresh browser)

Comment: Cheers @Jin, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same issue in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8489/arduino) without a retina display.

[image: no icon]

The root of the problem appears to be different than what Shadow points out since it's pulling from a [different location](http://cdn.sstatic.net/arduino/img/favicon.ico?v=abcdef):

```
<img class="small-site-logo" title="Arduino" alt="Arduino" width="16" height="16" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/arduino/img/favicon.ico?v=abcdef">
```

[image: icon]

Answer (score -1):

This may just be an error on your end. I would try to restart your computer and see if this fixes the problem. It may also be a zoom error. Try zooming in or out and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Nope, just reproed on a different machine. Try the steps above.